# How to remove PhpStorm auto added text on the codes

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

Does anyone knows how to remove the word "url" & "view" which is automatically added on the PHP storm IDE?

Check below image I have marked in red:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called [inlay hints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/viewing-reference-information.html#inlay-hints), you can find the settings for them here:

**Phpstorm 2017.1:**

> Editor | General | Appearance | Show parameter name hints

**Phpstorm 2019.3:**

> Settings | Editor | Inlay Hints | PHP | Parameter hints

[image]

Comment: i cant find php under "Inlay Hints" ?

Comment: Could you try the following: "Editor | General | Appearance | deselect Show parameter name hints"